# Deseleciconar Item en listview Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

necesito que cuando entras en el focus del viewcell, y si vuelves a tocar deseleccione ese selectedItem. He intentado listview.selecteditem = null, pero si hago esto no se vuelve a poder seleccionar nada..

Sabeis alguna forma de limpiar un listview tocando en el item ya seleccionado?
`void OnListViewItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            myListView.SelectedItem = true;
        }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el ListView tiene 2 eventos para ser ejecutadas al seleccionar la lista, `itemSelected` y `ItemTapped` las cuales debes marcar como null dentro del evento para lograr esos estado. ejemplo:

`void ListView_ItemSelect(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
 {
       ListView.SelectedItem = null;
 }
 void ListView_ ItemTapped(Object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
 {
       ListView.ItemTapped = null;
 }`

Para seleccionar un item de la lista solo debes hacer que cualquiera de las 2 propiedades del ListView obtenga el item index de la lista modelo de dicha ListView, debe tener en cuanta el tipo de evento que se ejecuta y como. Ejemplo:

`ItemSelected: Solo selecciona y retorna un objeto del modelo de la lista; se ejecuta cuando presionas el item de la lista.`

`ItemTapped: Solo selecciona y retorna un objeto del modelo de la lista; se ejecuta tras retirar el dedo del item.`

[Mas information, Recursos de Xamarin Form](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/)